# Rails Time.zone parsing doesn't work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, activesupport

I ran into this issue while testing a rails app deployed to two different staging servers, in different time zones (PDT and CDT). Both servers have rails using the default UTC config.time_zone. Apart from the timezone configuration being different, both servers have their clocks set correctly.

Below is what I see in a rails console:

On the server where system timezone is CDT,

```
Time.zone.parse("Mon May 28 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)")
 => Mon, 28 May 2012 05:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

On the server where system timezone is PDT,

```
Time.zone.parse("Mon May 28 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)")
 => Mon, 28 May 2012 07:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

The string `Mon May 28 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)` is an arbitrary date-time value sent by a client. This is a common scenario when using a javascript Date object coming in via the rails params collection.

**Why are the two results `Time.zone.parse(identical_date_time_string)` different?**

If I run the following on both systems, the result appears correct:

```
"Mon May 28 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)".to_time
 => 2012-05-28 07:00:00 UTC
```

I'm running rails 3.2.3 with ruby 1.9.3-p125, on ubuntu.

Comment: Opened an issue against rails https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5770

Comment: Managed to patch ActiveSupport::TimeZone to handle date strings of the format here. You can find the patch [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5770#issuecomment-5010661), in comments.

Comment: The original issue is now fixed in rails, with this commit https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/005d910624bbfa724b638426a000c8074d4201a2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActiveSupportTimeZone.parse` makes no attempt to extract the time zone information out of the given string.  It simply extracts the date and time and converts it to a TimeWithZone with the given (local) time zone.

`str.to_time` will take notice of the "GMT-0700" line, but will produce a time without a time zone.

You could fudge it by extracting the "GMT....." part and converting that to a UTC offset, which is close to, but not exactly, the time zone.

Comment: Hi Michael, I added more details about how the same date-time string is parsed correctly when using the ."to_time" method on the string. That works consistently and accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it

```
> Time.zone = "Hawaii"
=> "Hawaii"
> Time.zone.parse("Tue Mar 13 2012 13:00:00 GMT+1300 (NZDT)".sub("GMT",""))
=> Mon, 12 Mar 2012 14:00:00 HST -10:00
> Time.zone = "UTC"
=> "UTC"
> Time.zone.parse("Tue Mar 13 2012 13:00:00 GMT+1300 (NZDT)".sub("GMT",""))
=> Tue, 13 Mar 2012 00:00:00 UTC 00:00
```

Comment: Joseph, the issue is now fixed in rails. See https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/005d910624bbfa724b638426a000c8074d4201a2

Comment: @ShyamHabarakada Thanks for the tip. Glad they have finally got that sorted